# Header and Footer section are missing - jquery-scrollify

Tags: jquery-scrollify

In my wordpress site I am adding jquery-scrollify effect header and footer are missing ,..here I don't want use scroll effect for header and footer

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducable example

Comment: Are you using the interstitialSection scrollify config option?
As it states in the readme of the plugin: "interstitialSection: A CSS selector for non-full-height sections, such as a header and footer."